# How to check if AWS CLI SSO is logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-cli

I'm using aws sso login, but I can't found out how to discover if I'm already logged in or if I need to login again, the only way I found to do that is to run a command I know I have permission and check that no errors happen.

```
aws sso logout
aws sqs list-queues # error
aws sso login # brower accept
aws sqs list-queues # success
```

My goal with that is to automate some scripts and only ask for login if needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check for the sts caller identity call

> Returns details about the IAM user or role whose credentials are used to call the operation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html

```
#!/bin/bash

SSO_ACCOUNT=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query "Account" --profile sso)
#you can add a better check, but this is just an idea for quick check
if [ ${#SSO_ACCOUNT} -eq 14 ];  then 
echo "session still valid" ;
else 
echo "Seems like session expired"
# performed login here
fi
```

If the session is still valid, it will return

```
{
    "UserId": "AIDASAMPLEUSERID",
    "Account": "123456789012",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/DevAdmin"
}
```

If the session is not valid, it will return

```
The SSO session associated with this profile has expired or is otherwise invalid. To refresh this SSO session run aws sso login with the corresponding profile.
```

Or you can use this utility which is designed for this purpose

https://github.com/benkehoe/aws-sso-util

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out what `${#SSO_ACCOUNT} -eq 14` was checking, but thats looking for the returned value to be 14 characters (a 12 digit account number plus surrounding double-quotes)

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue recently, but opted for a solution using exit codes:

```bash
aws sts get-caller-identity &> /dev/null
EXIT_CODE="$?"  # $? is the exit code of the last statement
if [ $EXIT_CODE == 0 ]; then
    # auth is valid
else
    # auth needs refresh
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you've got more than one SSO session - it'd be valid for one but not for another.

Comment: Do you mean two sessions in the same script?

Answer (score 2):

I had a solution similar to @treyhakanson, but Setting EXIT_CODE has caused a problem somehow when I was doing a compare, e.g. if I call this function as a prerequisite to running another function that depends on being logged in, and I pressed ctrl+c during the login prompt (instead of mac+c) it caused it to bypass the login check altogether. So just checking `$?` straight across worked better for me.

Here's the full function:

```bash
# check if we have a valid sso login
# useful for when cron ran script so that it doesnt just get a bunch
#  of errors when your not logged in
function ssoLoginCheck () {
  aws sts get-caller-identity &> /dev/null
  # $? is the exit code of the last statement
  if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then
      # auth is valid
      echo "your sso token is valid, continuing"
  else
    if [ -t 1 ] ; then
      echo "Found that this is an interactive terminal, will run the sso login"
      # auth needs refresh
      aws sso login
      if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
        echo "You didnt login, exiting!"
        exit 1;
      fi
    else
      # is cron
      echo "Not in a tty, gracefully exiting due to no active SSO login. Check that your logged in via SSO, or have perms via IAM already setup";
      exit 1;
    fi
  fi
}
ssoLoginCheck;
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed this in python jupyter notebook and used below to achieve this.

**1. Python3**

```
import boto3
import os
def check_session_validity(profile="default"):
    try:
        boto3.Session(profile_name=profile).client('sts').get_caller_identity()
        print("Valid session")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Invalid session: hence logging using SSO")
        os.environ["AWS_PROFILE"] = profile
        import subprocess
        subprocess.run(["aws", "sso", "login"], check=True)
check_session_validity("my_profile")
```

**2. Shell Script** (same can be used in shell script automation):

```
#!/bin/bash

check_session_validity() {
    local profile="$1"
    if aws --profile "$profile" sts get-caller-identity >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Valid session"
    else
        echo "Invalid session: hence logging using SSO"
        export AWS_PROFILE="$profile"
        aws sso login
    fi
}

# Call the function with the specified profile name
check_session_validity "my_profile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Three different methods to determine if a user is logged in via SSO

```
SSO_ACCOUNT_PROFILE=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query "Account" --profile default)
SSO_ACCOUNT=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query "Account")

if [ ${#SSO_ACCOUNT_PROFILE} -eq 14 ] || [ ${#SSO_ACCOUNT} -eq 14 ] || aws sts get-caller-identity &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Session still valid"
    # Auth is valid
else
    echo "Seems like session expired"
    exit 1
fi
```